# AJAX GET request changing the referer

Tags: javascript, jquery, get, http-referer

I am using jQuery GET request to fetch some content and display it on page. The problem is that the page has a login button. It takes user to login screen and after successful login user get redirected to earlier page.

but in my case user is getting redirected to AJAX get Request URL.

Here is the code I am using to make AJAX request.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery.get('/morerecentblogs.jspa?communityId=2004&start=1&numResults=10&',
     function(data) { 
      jQuery('#recent-blogs').html(data) 
     }
)
```

After logging in user is getting redirected to

> /morerecentblogs.jspa?communityId=2004&start=1&numResults=10&

instead of the actual page.

Any idea what is wrong here? I have checked in HTTPFOX but there Referer is correct. It is actual URL but not ajax url

Comment: How you redirect? Can you post that code and any other relevant code on the server side?

Comment: more over you are adding get function as soon as doc is `ready`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($) { // Simplyfied jQuery ready method
    // $ is now jQuery and it's safe in this scope.

    $.ajax({ // Using ajax method instead.
        "url": "/morerecentblogs.jspa?communityId=2004&start=1&numResults=10",
        "type": "GET", // Type GET/POST
        "dataType": "html", //HTML/JSON/JSONP/XML
        "success": function(response) { // Your success handler
            $('#recent-blogs').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The AJAX call is correct. But the problem is it is changing the referer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have tried lot of things but finally changed the server side code and passed the return url as a parameter.